# Visual studio release management - deploy with ps/dsc encountered error with server certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl, release-management, ms-release-management, winrm

I'm trying to run a simple ps script on a target computer (my local machine) from our RM server through the RM client. However the release falls over when it reaches deploy using ps/dsc. The error message reads:

> Connecting to remote server ### failed with the following error message : The server certificate on the destination computer (###:5985) has the following errors:
>   Encountered an internal error in the SSL library.

However as you can see by the winrm port number, I'm using HTTP not HTTPS to communicate with my machine, so surely SSL should not come into it. So has anyone else come across this or have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** the machines are part of the same domain.

Comment: Can you run the script from RM server to the target through PS remoting?

Answer (score 0):

In the deploy using DSC action keep `UseHTTPS` variable to false and `skipCACheck` to true, just in case.

BTW, how long does it take for the action to show this error message in the logs? Also, as someone mentioned in the comments, are you able to manually run the script using PS remoting?

If none of the above helps, we would need more details. Try looking into the event logs for the target machine right after your deployment failed and check for any errors.

Comment: Yeah I had `UseHTTPS` as false and `SkipCaCheck` as true. It took the action 6 minutes 20 secs to show the error. Kerberos has decided to start working now so the PS scripts are running fine through RM. I was unable to test if I could remote in from the RM server as I don't have access to it. However, I tried remoting in from another machine on my domain using kerberos auth and it didn't work initially.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue ,On installing Azure service certification VM tailed,Resolved issue.